# Segmentation fault when trying to adapt "Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit"

Tags: linux, gcc, stack-overflow, code-injection, stack-smash

I am following the classic paper [Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) along side "Smashing the Stack in 2011". Despite all the Q/As about these papers I cannot find an answer to my problem.

I am trying to run a simple exit(0) command but with a call and jmp similar to shellcodeasm.c in "Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit" so I can follow the paper to the end (I managed to get this to work when I removed the call and jmp). Clearly my following shellcodeasm.c doesn't open a shell but I am keeping to the names in "Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit" so my process is easier to follow.

shellcodeasm.c

```
void main() {
__asm__("jmp 0xd \n \
        popl   %esi \n \
        movl   $0x1,%eax \n \
        movl   $0x0, %ebx \n \
        int    $0x80 \n \
        call   -0x12 \n \
        .string \"/bin/sh\" ");
}
```

Running `gcc -o shellcodeasm -g -ggdb shellcodeasm.c` and using gdb to get the hex from main+3 to the end of main (as in the paper) I can generate my testsc.c

testsc.c

```
char shellcode[] =
"\xe9\x29\x7c\xfb\xf7\x5e\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xf8\x7b\xfb\xf7\x2f\x62\x69"
"\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x5d\xc3";

void main() {
  int *ret;

  ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
  (*ret) = (int)shellcode;

}
```

I can then compile and run it using the techniques in "Smashing the Stack in 2011"

```
gcc -o testsc testsc.c -fno-stack-protector
execstack -s testsc
./testsc
```

But unfortunately I get a segmentation fault (as there are no buffer overflows here I guess -fno-stack-protector is not necessary but it doesn't work when I remove it either).

Does anyone know what I am not understanding/missing?

The output of `uname -a` is `Linux core 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u3 i686 GNU/Linux` and the output of `gcc -v` is `gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)`. I hope I have given all the relevant info.

Comment: Segmentation fault most likely means a page fault, i. e., a memory page is accessed which is not mapped. This can be caused by an invalid function return address on the stack. So you may already have ‘smashed the stack’ but the stack looks differently than expected by the author. You should run your program in a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: Changed my shellcodeasm.c to use labels instead

`void main() {
__asm__("jmp label1; \n \
        label2: \n \
        popl   %esi \n \
        movl   $0x1,%eax \n \
        movl   $0x0, %ebx \n \
        int    $0x80 \n \
        label1: \n \
        call   label2; \n \
        .string \"/bin/sh\" ");
}`

and it worked, how comes?